# HttpContextWrapper doesn't return correct host name

Tags: asp.net

I've created instance of `HttpContextWrapper` using new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current) and find host name. But it is doesn't return correct host name. Does it cache first instance of `httpcontext`? It is returning first entered host name rather than new one.

In development environment it is working fine but behind load balancer it is creating issues.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't use static type or Singleton type for HttpContextWrapper.

Comment: It's not static.